# Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "geo:point" with jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin

Tags: java, json

Hi I m getting the below exception when trying to call lastFM API from my java client application. I have used the jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin to auto generate my classes. I need the the lat and the long field (I dont want to ignore them)
The json Im trying to read is as follows:[LastFM API Call](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getevents&location=London&api_key=127e0a3d10d7109682963ccc5b88aadf&limit=20&format=json) . Any ideas?

```
location: {geo:point: {geo:lat: "51.539739",geo:long: "-0.102676"}
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "geo:point" (Class imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Location), not marked as ignorable
>    at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@6391b687; line: 1, column: 191] (through reference chain: imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.LastFMEventsDTO["events"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Events["event"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Event["venue"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Venue["location"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Location["geo:point"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "geo:point" (Class imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Location), not marked as ignorable
>    at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@6391b687; line: 1, column: 191] (through reference chain: imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.LastFMEventsDTO["events"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Events["event"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Event["venue"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Venue["location"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Location["geo:point"])
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:162)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:492)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:447)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:215)
>       at imis.athena.client.lastfm.run.LastFMRunner.initiateApiRequests(LastFMRunner.java:53)
>       at imis.athena.client.lastfm.run.LastFMRunner.initiateSpringContextAndRun(LastFMRunner.java:45)
>       at imis.athena.client.lastfm.run.LastFMRunner.main(LastFMRunner.java:39)
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "geo:point" (Class imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Location), not marked as ignorable
>    at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@6391b687; line: 1, column: 191] (through reference chain: imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.LastFMEventsDTO["events"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Events["event"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Event["venue"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Venue["location"]->imis.athena.client.lastfm.dto.Location["geo:point"])
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:194)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:30)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1923)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:167)
>       ... 8 more

**EDIT** problematic java class

> @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
>   @Generated("com.googlecode.jsonschema2pojo")
>   @JsonPropertyOrder({
>       "city",
>       "country",
>       "geo:point",
>       "postalcode",
>       "street"
>   })
>
> public class Location {

```
/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("city")
private String city;
/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("country")
private String country;
/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("geo:point")
private Geo_point geo_point;
/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("postalcode")
private String postalcode;
/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("street")
private String street;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("city")
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("city")
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("country")
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("country")
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("geo:point")
public Geo_point getGeo_point() {
    return geo_point;
}

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("geo:point")
public void setGeo_point(Geo_point geo_point) {
    this.geo_point = geo_point;
}

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("postalcode")
public String getPostalcode() {
    return postalcode;
}

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("postalcode")
public void setPostalcode(String postalcode) {
    this.postalcode = postalcode;
}

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("street")
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

/**
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("street")
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, other);
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperties(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe it's the colon between `geo` and `point`? Might not be supported?

Comment: Please attach your generated java classes.

Comment: attached the "faulty" class.